# Header tag sizing properties

Tags: html, header, styles, height, width

```
<body>
   <header height="100px" width="100px">
    <p>InstaText is a user-friendly paraphrasing tool that helps you rewrite your text. InstaText improves and enriches your content to make it more readable and understandable. Free registration. Rewriter. Rewrite online. Free trial. Paraphrase onlinenstaText is a user-friendly paraphrasing tool that helps you rewrite your text. InstaText improves and enriches your content to make it more readable and understandable. Free registration. Rewriter. Rewrite online. Free trial. Paraphrase onlinenstaText is a user-friendly paraphrasing tool that helps you rewrite your text. InstaText improves and enriches your content to make it more readable and understandable. Free registration. Rewriter. Rewrite online. Free trial. Paraphrase onlinenstaText is a user-friendly paraphrasing tool that helps you rewrite your text. InstaText improves and enriches your content to make it more readable and understandable. Free registration. Rewriter. Rewrite online. Free trial. Paraphrase online</p>
```

if i use the height and width with img it works but why wont it work on header tag?

Answer (score 0):

The dimension attributes are designed to allow a website to specify what size an external resource is so a placeholder can be provided before it loads.

A `header` element doesn't load an external resource.

---

If you want to specify the dimensions of an element for layout, you can [use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics), which was introduced in 1996.